# Location of webdav mounted from nautilus

Tags: nautilus, webdav

If I have mounted a webdav share using Nautilus, has it been mounted somewhere on the filesystem that I can access on the command line? If so, where?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally found where this is --  it's in

```
 /run/user/1000/gvfs/host....
```

where the '1000' is the uid of the user that mounted it.